# The work of a method

Tags: java, methods

```
static int gcd(int x, int y) {
    if (y==0)  return x;
    return gcd(y, x%y);
}
```

When my `x = 585` and `y = 78` the number of steps that my method does before giving the result is 3. When I change the order, `x = 78` and `y = 585` the number of steps is 4. What is the cause of this dependence? I tried few pairs of integers and always when `x > y` the number of steps is `a`, then after the change the number is `a + 1`.

I tried to ask about it yesterday, I hope now I am more clear and precise.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from taking a piece of paper and a pencil and doing the math yourself? How otherwise would *you* answer this question being asked by somebody else?

Comment: Please tag your questions with the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear, after putting a few `System.out.println` in your code, that your method intentionally switches the numbers, before proceeding to finding GCD. Here's the output from `585, 78`:

> Made another call. X = 585 Y = 78
>   Made another call. X = 78 Y = 39
>   Made another call. X = 39 Y = 0
>   39

And here is the output from `78, 585`:

> Made another call. X = 78 Y = 585
>   Made another call. X = 585 Y = 78
>   Made another call. X = 78 Y = 39
>   Made another call. X = 39 Y = 0
>   39

The extra call is coming from switching the two numbers around.

**Explanation**

If we dry run the first execution of this code, with the largest number first, we've got:

```
x = 585
y = 78

y is not equal to 0 so don't return x.

make recursive call with: y in the place of x. (this is the switch)
x % y in the place of y (585 % 78 = 39)
```

And if we go with the smallest number first:

```
x = 78
y = 585

y is not equal to 0 so don't return x
make recursive call with: y in the place of x (so first argument is 585)
x % y in the place of y ( 78 % 585 = 78)
```

The extra call is to swap the two values around, and from the modulo operation it's clear that this should happen, given for any `x` and `y`, given `x < y` and `x > 0`, `x % y = x`. If the smaller number remained in the `x` position, the algorithm would just run and run.

Comment: yes the switching is intentional. see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm